# Will unique values in uint64_t also be unique in int64_t

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Given a vector of unique (`std::uint64_t` type) integers, if I cast vector of (`std::uint64_t` type) to vector of (`std::int64_t` type) integers, will it be guaranteed to be unique?

Casting like this

```
std::vector<std::uint64_t> unsignedVec;
std::vector<std::int64_t> signedVec( unsignedVec.begin(), unsignedVec.end() );
```

Comment: What do you mean by generate, cast?

Comment: Maybe. How will you generate the vector of `std::int64_t`?

Comment: What do you mean 'generate'? If you mean 'cast', your original integers would either be smaller or equal than maximum value representable by `int64` (and in this case identical to original `uint64_t` numbers), or your program will exhibit undefined behavior, and anything can happen.

Comment: @SergeyA Casting unsigned type to a signed type is not undefined behaviour. Overflowing signed integer is, not casting to it.

Comment: @Resurrection casting integrals into unrepresentable ranges is undefined, and this is exactly what I have said.

Comment: Not all values representable by `uint64_t` can be represented by `int64_t`

Comment: @JesperJuhl As stated, it seems that this question is about the *uniqueness* of the transformation, rather than the resulting values.

Comment: But we can't make that guarantee as for many values of uint64 the result in int64 is not defined. In most implementations they will just generate corresponding unique negative numbers, but a compiler is allowed to set them all to MAX_INT_64 or zero, or clear the sign bit - making them not unique versus the inrange values, or exception, or delete the contents of your hard disk, or anything really. If you cause the next extinction event, don't come running to me! BTW, this is a much better excuse than the dog ate my homework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> will it be guaranteed to be unique?

Formally it's implementation-defined, but on any sensible platform it should be unique.

<sup>(Especially given that `int64_t` [has to be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) 2's complement if it's provided.)</sup>

Since C++20 it *has* to be unique.

---

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_conversions
>
> If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type. [Otherwise the result is implementation-defined (until C++20)] [the unique value of the destination type equal to the source value modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>    where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type. (since C++20)].

Comment: If [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is correct, an `int64_t` is a "signed integer type with width of exactly 64 bits **with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values** (provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)" Can we assume that if it is provided, it is *always* 2's complement?

Comment: @Bob__ I've checked the standard and the page is correct. Huh, I didn't know that was required. But I think I'll leave "any sensible two's complement platform" wording for clarity.

Comment: Well, in that case, I guess that a quote from the standard may be a good addition to your answer ;)

Comment: @Bob__ very good catch, I totally forgot about that! I guess, based on that, one can argue that it's unique even on C++11. I added what I believe to be the relevant quotes to my answer if anyone's interested…

Comment: @MichaelKenze Well, it says "implementation-defined". Even if it's 2's complement, the conversion is still implementation-defined.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat hm, I guess you're technically correct…

Comment: @Bob__ You mean a quote saying `int*_t` are 2's complement? Eh, I don't think it adds anything to the answer. It's implementation-defined pre-C++20 either way.

Answer (score 3):

The values ending up in `signedVec` using

```
std::vector<std::int64_t> signedVec( unsignedVec.begin(), unsignedVec.end() );
```

will be implementation-defined in C++11 if the corresponding value in `unsignedVec` is larger than what `std::int64_t` can represent. Otherwise, the value will be the same [[conv.integral]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.integral#3):

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

Note: C++11 inherits the definition of `std::int64_t` from C99 via [[headers]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/headers#4). `int64_t` is specified in C99 [7.18.1.1]/1 as (emphasis mine; thanks to [@Bob__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4944425/bob) for pointing this out):

> The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width *N*, **no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation**.

and [7.18.1.1]/3

> These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

So while it is technically still implementation-defined, it is very unlikely that the values will not be unique if the code compiles (which it only will if `std::int64_t` is defined, as that is optional). Since `int64_t` is specified to have a two's-complement representation and is only defined if the implementation can support that, for the conversion to behave in any other than the expected way would be very surprising. I've never heard of a compiler where it would not behave as expected. Furthermore, as pointed out in the [answer by @HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56157558/2064761), the desired behavior will be required starting with C++20 [[conv.integral]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#3)…

Answer (score 1):

With given code two possible scenario exists:

- All elements of original vector `unsignedVec` are lesser than or equal to `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()`. In this case target vector elements would be identical to original vector elements, and all their properties would be preserved.
- There are elements in the original vector which are greater than `std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max()`. In this case program behavior is not defined in the Standard, is left up to the implementation, and anything can happen.

Comment: Isn't it implementation-defined?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the first case is defined by the standard. Assigning an unsigned integer type to a signed integer type is well-defined as long as the value of the unsigned integer does not exceed the acceptable range of the signed integer type. The second case is *undefined* by the standard and indeed depends on to compiler implementation.

Comment: @SergeyA The answer says the behavior is undefined, but it's implementation-defined. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_conversions

Comment: @HolyBlackCat bad choice of words, I meant it is not defined. I edited for clarity.

Comment: I am sorry but your wording is still misleading. "not defined in the Standard" is the same as saying it is "undefined" and is incorrect because standard defines it as "implementation defined" and since C++20 defines it directly. "Anything can happen" is at least misleading because it is used exclusively when describing undefined behaviour which this case is not.

Comment: @Resurrection I have no interest in splitting hairs. In my view, it is not defined in the Standard (because it is not), and it is up to implementation to do what it wants - thus anything can happen, since OP doesn't tag any specific implementation. My answer doesn't account for C++ 20, because it is not published, and without any specific C++ dialect tags I assume latest published standard.

Comment: @SergeyA The "not defined in the standard" and "anything can happen" expressions are used often when talking about C++ and they have very clear and precise meaning which is different than what you are trying to convey in your answer. That is why I consider it misleading especially for people without such a strong grasp of a language. May I propose an edit or do you prefer to keep it this way?

Comment: @Resurrection I prefer it to keep this way, thanks.